# Having textView in tableView Cell, The textView does not become First responder at all

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I just have a custom table view cell. When I put a `UITextField` rather than the `UITextView`, it's ok. And when I touch the `UITextField` in app it becomes first responder and I can type in it. But when I replace it with a `UITextView`, it does not responsd any more and does not become first responder. How can I fix this? I need a multiline text field in my custom cell so I should use `UITextView`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you showed some of the relevant code that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, There is no special code, I just have a cell with a textview. every thing is ok and the cell works fine with the textfields above but when I add the textView rather than the textfield and tap the textview to write something s doesn't response and the keyboard doesn't appear too. all things are in storyBoard so I can't show any code for now :)

Comment: Have you enabled user interaction for the text view?